# What is the best way to implement nested ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a multi-client architecture in a spring-mvc based web server residing on tomcat. If I wish to have a multi-threading mechanism where each client gets 5 thread pools which can have 5 max threads per user running parallel, are there any such implementations available in Java? If not, then what will be the best way to implement that?

Comment: No reasons for downvote?

Comment: Sounds like you want a pool of thread pools.  Pooling objects is a very common design pattern.  You can find lots of examples of it by googling for "object pool".  But unless every client has five background threads working at all times, you're going to have a lot of idle threads.  I'd consider using just one pool of threads, and implement some mechanism that prevents any one client from using more than five of them at once.